# pasar parámetros de esta librería de para generar codigo Qr barcode.php

Tags: javascript, php, html5

Genere códigos de barras a partir de un único archivo PHP. licencia del MIT. .

alguien me puede ayudar con los parámetros de  esta librería de  para generar código Qr.

el problema es como se le puede pasar parámetros de ancho y alto del  código Qr. estoy utilizando esta librería    [https://github.com/kreativekorp/barcode]

```phtml
 <section  class="boxqr">
                 <div id="qr" class="mover">
                  <?php                              
                  $qr="qr";
                  include "js/barcode/barcode.php";
                  $generator = new barcode_generator();
                  $options=array($w='10', $h='10');
                  $svg = $generator->render_svg($qr,$_SESSION["cedulax"].' '.$_SESSION["nombreest"].' '.$_SESSION["apellidoest"],$options);
                   echo $svg;
                  
                 
            
                  ?>
                 </div> 
                 </section>
```

¿Cómo pasarle parámetros para el tamaño del código QR?.

[image: como pasarle parámetros para mover y cambiar de tamaño al código QR.]

Comment: y que dice la documentacion de la libreria???

Comment: ademas creo que puedes facilmente controlar el tamaño de la imagen con css

Comment: En la documentación aparece claramente https://github.com/kreativekorp/barcode#options `w` y `h` para las dimensiones y `sf` , `sx` y `sy` para las escalas

Comment: ya intente con Css y nada esta es la librería estoy utilizando, https://github.com/kreativekorp/barcode.
como pasarle el parámetro del tamaño en el código

Comment: creo que decir que usas una libreria no esta ayudando.

Comment: muchas gracias ya pude pasarle parámetros resulto. 
<section  class="boxqr">
                 <div id="qr" class="mover">
                  <?php                              
                  $qr="qr";
                  include "js/barcode/barcode.php";
                  $generator = new barcode_generator();
      $options=array('sx'=>2.5,
       'sy'=>2.5,'p'=>-12);
      $svg = $generator->render_svg($qr,$_SESSION["cedulax"].' '.$_SESSION["nombreest"].' '.$_SESSION["apellidoest"],$options);  echo $svg;  ?>

Answer (score 0):

De esta forma se puede pasar parámetros para dar estilo al código QR con la librería Barcodephp

```php
<section  class="boxqr">
    <div id="qr" class="mover">
     <?php                              
          $qr="qr";
          include "js/barcode/barcode.php";
          $generator = new barcode_generator();
          $options=array('sx'=>2.5,'sy'=>2.5,'p'=>-12);
          $svg = $generator->render_svg($qr,$_SESSION["cedulax"].' '.$_SESSION["nombreest"].' '.$_SESSION["apellidoest"],$options);
          echo $svg;
     ?>
    </div>  
</section>
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).